# Filling some web form programmatically using WebBrowser WPF control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, web

I need to pre-fill some form in some web page within my WPF app (The web page is in an external website), i am using WPF WebBrowser control.

Is there are some way to do it.

I have some suggestion: emulating keyboard strocks and use tab key to move through fields, (How to do this).

**EDIT**

The desired form is so sophisticated and the names of the elements are dynamic, but they are always in the same order.

Comment: If this external website wanted you to do this, it would provide API.

Comment: There is no API, however i won't misuse it in illegal places!

Comment: Most of the time names/ids of fields are static and easy to post an automated answer. But if they are dynamic as you said, then that means they don't want you to do this post programmatically.

Comment: However i'll do it, because there are no clear legal prevention from them!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you want to submit a form you check this

```
     // get the document
     mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 doc = ((mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass)webBrowser1.Document);

     // set a variable
     ((mshtml.IHTMLElement)doc.all.item("q")).setAttribute("value", "my input...");

     // click a button
    ((mshtml.HTMLInputElement)doc.all.item("btnI")).click();
```

the namespace `mshtml` is located in `Microsoft.mshtml` Assembly.

Just add reference Microsoft.mshtml.

hope this helps

Comment: Its a namespace. Just add reference Microsoft.mshtml.

Comment: Is it existed on any machine with .net or should be deployed separately?

Comment: You could set the reference as "local copy" (assembly is part of your bin folder) to make sure its everytime avaliable.