# How to auto fill a text box in C#

Tags: c#, web

If I have a c# application with a webbrowser built in it and I navigate to a website. I want my application to find the first textbox IE: email and fill it with Xtacy and then the second text box Password with Password.

[image]

Comment: Post the relevant portion of the HTML code with the form

Comment: Refer this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7861026/500725), it might help you.

Answer (score 3):

You should find the Textbox control and set the value as follows:

```
HtmlDocument doc = this.webBrowser1.Document;
doc.GetElementById("IE").SetAttribute("Value", "Xtacy");
doc.GetElementById("Password").SetAttribute("Value", "Password");
```

Answer (score 2):

You should look at the docs. The [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5d67hf8a.aspx) class has a [Document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.document.aspx) property. This returns an [HtmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.aspx) which will give you access to the DOM.

Next, you use the [GetElementById()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementbyid.aspx) to get the input box like below and then set it's value with the [SetAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.setattribute.aspx) method.

```
HtmlDocument d = this.yourWebBrowser.Document;
d.GetElementById("<id of IE input>").SetAttribute("value", "Xtacy");
d.GetElementById("<id password input>").SetAttribute("value", "Password");
```